# No $$hashKey on angularjs object in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

$scope.create (in CreateCtrl) and $scope.list (inListCtrl) linked to DOM
For some reason, $ $ hashKey not added to all objects. The last object is left without him. That is, if I added 3 items, the third less $ $ hashkey if add another, then a third appears hashkey $ $, and the fourth is not.

Because of this error appears: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

track by $index does not offer. Then sorting stops working.

```
app.controller('CreateCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.create = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
   $scope.send = function () {
      $scope.$emit('send', angular.copy($scope.create));
   }
});

app.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
   $scope.list = [];
   $rootScope.$on('send', function (e, data) {
      $scope.list.push(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: One thing, if your ListCtrl is a child of CreateCtrl you should use `$scope.$broadcast` and then `$scope.$on` and then you don't need to inject `$rootScope` into the ListCtrl.

Comment: ListCtrl no child for CreateCtrl

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a javascript object `{}` with three elements and then pushing that whole object into the first index of `$scope.list`

```
$rootScope.$on('send',function(e,data){
    angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
        $scope.list.push(value); // or $scope.list[key] = value;
    });
});
```

Your values are at `data.a`, `data.b` and `data.c`

Comment: No, my $ scope.list should look like: $scope.list = [{a:1,b:2,c:3}, {a:1,b:2,c:3}, {a:1,b:2,c:3}] (only with $$hashKey, but not the last element of $$hashKey) My problem is that the array looks like this: $scope.list = [{$$hashKey:'aa', a:1,b:2,c:3}, { $$hashKey: 'bb', a:1,b:2,c:3}, {a:1,b:2,c:3}] (The latter element is never $$hashKey)

Comment: the $$hashKey i believe is created/added in by `ngRepeat,` maybe you need to force a `$digest` by using `$scope.$apply`